# Exception org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException - apache.Poi 4.0.0

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read a Microsoft Word 2016 document but I can't...

```
private String readDoc(String path) {
String content = "";
try {
    File file = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());

    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);

    WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
    String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
    for (String para : paragraphs) {
        content += para.toString();
    }
    fis.close();
    return content;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return content;
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)

I don't get it... why does it give me this Exception, because I am not using any XSSF (I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.docx");
XWPFDocument xdoc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(xdoc);
System.out.println(extractor.getText());
```

It can help understand this:

> **POIFS** (Poor Obfuscation Implementation File System) − This component
>   is the basic factor of all other POI elements. It is used to read
>   different files explicitly.
>
> **HSSF** (Horrible SpreadSheet Format) − It is used to read and write .xls
>   format of MS-Excel files.
>
> **XSSF** (XML SpreadSheet Format) − It is used for .xlsx file format of
>   MS-Excel.
>
> **HPSF** (Horrible Property Set Format) − It is used to extract property
>   sets of the MS-Office files.
>
> **HWPF** (Horrible Word Processor Format) − It is used to read and write
>   .doc extension files of MS-Word.
>
> **XWPF** (XML Word Processor Format) − It is used to read and write .docx
>   extension files of MS-Word.
>
> **HSLF** (Horrible Slide Layout Format) − It is used to read, create, and
>   edit PowerPoint presentations.
>
> **HDGF** (Horrible DiaGram Format) − It contains classes and methods for
>   MS-Visio binary files.
>
> **HPBF** (Horrible PuBlisher Format) − It is used to read and write
>   MS-Publisher files.